# Magento 1: change setting Display out of stock products to NO & effect on performance of indexers and db

Tags: magento-1.9, performance

Question: how much effect does disabling the setting `Display out of stock products to NO in Stock options` have?

Does it improve indexer speed? Does it improve layered navigation building? Does it improve DB lookups?

We are asking becuase we have 80% old products out of stock from previous years that do nothing and will not come back